# Mongodb schema design meteor js

Tags: mongodb, database-design, meteor

I'm making a site with meteorjs that has users and each user can make a list that is viewable and shareable by everyone.  My question is about making an efficient mongodb schema.

- Should I have a collection for users and a separate collection for
  posts and tie both of those together?
- Or should I have just one collection that has users, and under each
  user there's a property that holds the posts?
- Or is there another way to do this?

I've looked up various schema designs, but I'm confused on how to work a user's collection in with a 'posts' collection.

Any documentation, answers, or sense of direction would be greatly appreciatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't create your own users collection, use the accounts packages.

Generally, a document in a document database is a set of data that will be displayed at the same time (not always true, but the idea is to construct a page from as few documents as possible). For your use case, I would have a `posts` collection which has a `userId` field and a `comments` array, each of which also has a `userId` field. You could also store a subset of the user data in each post/comment - especially if that data can not change.

Note that this is a fundamentally different approach than with a SQL database, where we always want to normalize our data and join records as needed. In a document database, it's better to denormalize as much data as we can to optimize performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be your best resource for everything mongoDB related (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/)

The comments use case is the closest to what you have in mind.